# how to copy popup window text message and paste into Excel file using selenium

Tags: selenium

I want to copy popup window Text Message and paste that message into Excel file and then compare that data with Actual data. I am able to read the popup window text message and display on consol window, But how to paste that message into excel file

Comment: I am using selenium java code for the same.

Comment: you need to download Apache poi(which is the API to deal with Excel to write read) and use it

Answer (score 0):

Selenium doesn't provide any functionality to deal with Excel documents, however assuming you're using Java you can read and write Excel files using [Apache POI](https://poi.apache.org/) library

```
Workbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook();   
CreationHelper createHelper = wb.getCreationHelper();
Sheet sheet = wb.createSheet("Sheet1");

Row row = sheet.createRow(0);
Cell cell = row.createCell(0);
cell.setCellValue(createHelper.createRichTextString("Hello world")); 

FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("workbook.xls");
wb.write(fileOut);
fileOut.close();
```

Hope it will help you.

Comment: yes I need to use external library for excel file. I want to copy popup message into excel file. My concern is how to copy popup window text message and paste into excel file. I have done below code

Comment: driver.switchTo().window(newBrowserWin);

   //Display popup message on Console
   newBrowserWinText = driver.findElement(By.tagName("tbody")).getText();                                                                                                               System.out.println("popup window message is:"+newBrowserWinText);
  }